# Grammar Question? 他没看了电影

Tags: grammar

Why is this grammatically incorrect
他没看了电影

The  没 is negating the past action. What am I missing?

Comment: It should be 他没看电影

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Negation_of_past_actions_with_%22meiyou%22#Go_Easy_on_the_.E4.BA.86_.28le.29) for an explanation.

[image]

While others have already pointed this out, they seem to have not mentioned that 过 could be appropriately used here. The sentence 他没看过电影 emphasizes that they have never seen the movie before, or that they have never experienced seeing the movie. On the other hand, 他没看电影 could simply imply that he hadn't watched a movie that he had planned on watching, even if they had seen the movie before.

So if you are planning to watch a movie for the second time, but don't, then you could say 我没看电影 (I hadn't watched the movie) vs 我没看过电影 (I haven't watched the movie *before*)

So 没V where V is a verb indicates that the action did not occur (context is key), while 没V过 indicates that it has never occurred

Comment: The referenced material is not quite correct, for example, "家裡的油沒有了"; "車沒有油了", both are grammatically correct, however "家裡沒有了油" and "車沒有了油", while understandable, they are problematic, as the first two can be standalone sentences, but not the latter two, which need more description to make them the full sentences.

Answer (score 0):

了 is the auxiliary word, used after a verb or adjective, to indicate the completion of the action，and express **affirmation**.

So, "He watched the movie" -> "他看了电影", "He did not watched the movie" -> "他没看电影", rather than "他没看了电影"